# IP or winsock interception?

Tags: c#, tcp, winsock

We have a terminal emulator (its more then just this, but for the question it best describe what it it...) Sometime ago instead of rewriting it a port proxy was introduced. the proxy listens to 127.0.0.1 loopback and takes the connection and encrypts it using SSL.

What I need to do is get the data from the local machine before it goes in to the proxy so we can check it and stop or change it. I can't change the configuration of the current setup so I need to find a way to get the data before its sent. can this be done using winsock? any other approaches?

thanks

Comment: There must be *something* you can change if you're considering trying to intercept it at the library level. Why not another proxy, between the app and the encrypting one?

Comment: thanks shambulator another proxy would be the easiest approach however the Terminal only allows you to change the target IP address and the current proxy always listens on the same address 127.0.0.1 on a fixed port! so no way of putting another proxy in line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Layered Service Provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) should do it (one is presumbably inside fiddler, so if that works for you, that's going to be quicker

Comment: Thanks Currently looking into this trying to find a c# example

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to listen in to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You should use some Win32 API Hook library.

Maybe [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) or [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).