# How to set internet Proxy and Port without affecting the SYSTEM/IE proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

I use this code in order to change proxy of internet in my C# application:

```
RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
            registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
            registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", "127.0.0.1:80);
            settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

After running the program, when I go to internet properties in IE, I can see that Proxy server has been changed:

[image]

My question: How can I change Proxy without affecting IE settings. I mean that when proxy is changed, If I check Internet properties, no changes are made.

Comment: What do you want to change the proxy for? Either you are changing it for a specific program or you are changing it generally. If a specific program you shoudl say what. If generally you'll have to explain how the above isn't what you want.

Comment: Ok this was how it reached here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513560/how-proxifier-program-sets-port-and-proxy

Comment: @Chris: I want to set this proxy an port on my computer in such way that if another person checked my IE proxy setting, he/she cannot see what I'm doing. I know programs that do this, But I want to know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but I think it looks like they intercept calls being made to winsock and modify them to be proxyaware. So effectively every time you create a network call out of your program it gets caught by your proxy-prog which passes it on to winsock with proxying information added.

[IP or winsock interception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277027/ip-or-winsock-interception) seems to ask a very similar question so exploring the answer on that might give you the answer. That is just about trying to read a network connection but some of the googling I've done does suggest that a Layered Service Provider could be what you need and that Detours might also be something to look at.